# Dynamic Variable in to Session

Tags: c#, session, dynamic

is there any way to store dynamic variable on session?

i tried this way

```
public dynamic MSG
{
    get
    {
        var obj = _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("MSG");
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj);
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        _context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MSG", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
}
```

but getting compilation error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1973  'ISession' has no applicable method named 'SetString' but
>   appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods
>   cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic
>   arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method
>   syntax.

Comment: use  `Session["MSG"]` instead of `Session.GetString("MSG")`

Answer (score 2):

Just do what error message says. Either don't use extension method, which cannot be dynamically dispatched, or use extension method explicitly, or just cast dynamic value to appropriate type:

```
_context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MSG", (string) JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below.

```
_context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MSG", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic types with extension methods is not yet supported.
You should cast the value of:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)
```

Just doing something like this should work:

```
_context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("MSG", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value).ToString());
```

Or use an other method, such as `Add` if present:

```
_context.HttpContext.Session.Add("MSG", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
```

#### Update

I just setup a little test.
By having the property structured like this, i didn't got any problem:

```
public dynamic MSG
    {
        get
        {
            string obj = HttpContext.Current.Session["MSG"].ToString();
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj) ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MSG"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        }
    }
```

However, of what type `_context` is? Maybe there are some differences with that object.

Comment: non of solutions works .. still throws same exception